# Why does SQLite return the wrong value from a subquery?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given a schema and data in SQLite 3.7.17 (I'm stuck with this version):

```
CREATE TABLE reservations (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,NodeID INTEGER,ifIndex INTEGER,dt TEXT,action TEXT,user TEXT,p TEXT);
INSERT INTO "reservations" VALUES(1,584,436211200,'2022-03-12 10:10:00','R','s','x');
INSERT INTO "reservations" VALUES(2,584,436211200,'2022-03-12 10:10:01','R','s','x');
INSERT INTO "reservations" VALUES(3,584,436211200,'2022-03-12 10:10:05','U','s','x');
INSERT INTO "reservations" VALUES(4,584,436211200,'2022-03-12 10:09:01','R','s','x');
```

I'm trying to get the most recent action for each pair of (NodeID,ifIndex).

Running `SELECT MAX(dt),action FROM reservations GROUP BY NodeId,ifIndex;` I get:

```
MAX(dt)|action
2022-03-12 10:10:05|U
```

Perfect.
Now I want to select just the action from this query (dropping the MAX(dt)): `SELECT t.action FROM (SELECT MAX(dt),action FROM reservations GROUP BY NodeId,ifIndex) AS t;`:

```
t.action
R
```

This I don't understand.  Also: `SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT MAX(dt),action FROM reservations GROUP BY NodeId,ifIndex) AS t;`:

```
MAX(dt)|action
2022-03-12 10:10:05|U
```

gives the correct value.  So why does the query not seem to be querying against the subquery?
Perhaps it's a bug in this version of SQLite as SQLFiddle works fine (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f7619a/4)

In attempt to workaround this issue I use this query: `SELECT t2.action FROM (SELECT MAX(dt),* FROM reservations GROUP BY NodeId,ifIndex) AS t1 INNER JOIN reservations AS t2 on t1.id = t2.i` which seems to work:

```
action
U
```

Comment: alias for MAX(dt) in your subquery?

Comment: What does `SELECT action FROM reservations GROUP BY NodeId,ifIndex HAVING MAX(dt);` return?

Comment: `U` (which is correct)

Comment: The SQLite behavior is fine, it's the query which is problematic.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz there is nothing problematic with the query. Here: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query you can find the documentation. This has to be a bug in the version used by the OP. The problem is not reproducible in later versions.

Comment: @forpas, (1) This syntax counts on internal implementation which is against everything SQL stands for as a declarative language (2) Change of behavior doesn't indicate a bug in previous versions. For years Oracle SQL developers avoided using "order by" after "group by" in order to save extra text, unnecessary sort operation or whatever they thought it would save - because the results where already sorted. And than one day Oracle introduced hash based aggregation and hell broke loose.

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz both (1) and (2) have nothing to do with a **documented behavior** that works fine and with great performance compared to alternatives up to the current version which is 3.38.0 A bug(?) in version 3.7.17 (2013) that is already fixed does not mean that anyone will stop using such unique but useful behavior.

Comment: I think this is a grey area. I'd classify the behavior of version 3.7.17 as a bug - at least in hindsight, the [documentation from May 2013](https://web.archive.org/web/20130527022250/https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) does not say anything about bare columns, so it was undocumented at the time. But then again, I would never have encountered this behavior, because I never use bare columns in an aggregate query as a matter of principle. Writing unambiguous SQL that does not lean on engine implementation details has its merits.

Comment: @forpas -  by all means, use on your own risk. The first OP query worked just fine, as documented. Once he stepped into the grey area, trying to "trick" the SQL engine, counting on it to first execute the subquery - he discovered that the engine has its own tricks.

Comment: Seems that this was fixed in version 3.8.0 (ironically exactly one release after the OP's), [the change log states](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_8_0) *"Bug fix: Bare identifiers in ORDER BY clauses bind more tightly to output column names, but identifiers in expressions bind more tightly to input column names. Identifiers in GROUP BY clauses always prefer output column names, however."*, which sounds suspiciously relate to what we're seeing here.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, this seems to be a bug in your SQLite version.

To get into more detail, you are using SQLite's `GROUP BY` extension **"Bare columns in an aggregate query"**.

In standard SQL and almost all RDBMS your query

```
SELECT MAX(dt), action FROM reservations GROUP BY NodeId, ifIndex;
```

is invalid. Why is that? You group by NodeId and ifIndex, thus aggregating your data down to one result row per NodeId and ifIndex. In each such row you want to show the group's maximum date and the group's action. But while there is one maximum date for a group, there is no *one* action for it, but *several*. Your query is considered invalid in standard SQL, because you don't tell the DBMS which of the group's actions you want to see. This could be the minimum action for example (i.e. the first in alphabetical order). That means there must be an aggregation function invoked on that column.

Not so in SQLite. When SQLite finds a "bare column" in a `GROUP BY` query that is meant to find a `MAX` or `MIN` of a column, it considers this to mean to take the bare column's value from the row where the minimum or maximum is found in. This is an extension to the SQL standard, and SQLite is the only DBMS I know of to feature this. You can read about this in the SQLite docs: Search "Bare columns in an aggregate query" in https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset.

```
SELECT MAX(dt), action FROM reservations GROUP BY NodeId, ifIndex;
```

hence finds the action in the row with the maximum dt. If you selected `MIN(dt)` instead, it would get you the action of the row with the minimum dt.

And of course a query selecting from a subquery result should still get the same value. It seems, however, that in your version SQLite gets confused with its bare column detection. It doesn't throw an error telling you it doesn't know which action to select, but it doesn't select the maximum dt's action either. Obviously a bug.

In standard SQL (and almost any RDBMS) your original query would be written like this:

```
SELECT dt, action 
FROM reservations r
WHERE dt =
(
  SELECT MAX(dt)
  FROM reservations mr
  WHERE mr.NodeId = r.NodeId AND mr.ifIndex = r.ifIndex
);
```

or like this:

```
SELECT dt, action 
FROM reservations r
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM reservations gr
  WHERE gr.NodeId = r.NodeId
  AND gr.ifIndex = r.ifIndex
  AND gr.dt > r.dt
);
```

or like this:

```
  SELECT dt, action
  FROM
  (
    SELECT dt, action, MAX(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY NodeId, ifIndex) AS max_dt
    FROM reservations
  ) with_max_dt
  WHERE dt = max_dt;
```

And there are still other ways to get the top row(s) per group.

In any of these proper SQL queries, you can remove dt from the select list and still get the maximum dt's action.

Comment: The other RDBMS that allows bare columns in aggregate queries without flinching is MySQL, I would not be surprised if the OP is used to that.

Comment: Nothing indicates a bug here. Since the `max(dt)` is not part of the result set, there is no need to execute it, therefore there is no reason that a value from the record with the max value would be presented

Comment: @David It's at least surprising behavior (when you expect that the subquery materializes, which is not entirely unreasonable) and it's different from what a more current SQLite versions do.

Comment: You can never expect a subquery to materialize. Optimizers just love to fold them.

Comment: @David דודו Markovitz: I disagree. That we can surmise how this happens internally does not mean it's not a bug. The subquery result is deterministic, and its action is guaranteed to be the one taken from the max dt row. A query result is a table in SQL. So if I select from this result table, then how can I possibly get an action that is not in that result table? This is definetely a bug.

Comment: @Tomalak: Yes, MySQL allows bare columns, but it doesn't have this special feature. MySQL, when not in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode, selects an *arbitrarily chosen value* from the group in this situation (i.e. it silently applies `ANY_VALUE` on the bare columns). SQLite is guaranteed to pick the value from the row(s) with the maximum dt instead.

Comment: This is not how optimizers works. "A subquery result" is not even a thing

Comment: @David דודו Markovitz: This is how *SQL* works. An optimizer is there to find the best way to get the data, but it is not allowed to change the result. The DBMS (probably its optimizer) is buggy here. And yes, a subquery result aka derived table is a "thing", it is a SQL table (albeit not one stored in the database).

Comment: This is certainly not how SQL works. It's an attempt to manipulate the engine and take advantage of a non-standard internal behavior. It didn't work.  And no, subqueries are syntax elements, not execution elements. `select * from (select * from (select * from (select * from (select * from t) t) t) t) t` will result in scanning the table's data just once, not 5 times. It would simply be executed as `select * from t`

Comment: @David דודו Markovitz: You are wrong. We are not talking about internal behavior, but a well-documented feature in SQLite. As to your query: I don't care how the DBMS executes this; I care about the result. If I would only get 50% of the rows in t and you told me what the optimizer might have done internally explaining the mutilated result, I'd still say this is a bug.

Comment: First, as already established by @Tomalak in the post comments, bare columns behavior was not documented for that version, so defiantly not a bug. Second, whether documented or not, it is by definition an internal behavior, since nothing in the query syntax implies it. Other database /SQL engines also have their unique way of achieving the same result, but it is backed by the SQL syntax.

Comment: Great responses.  I'm very interested in the difference between `SELECT t.action FROM (SELECT MAX(dt),action FROM reservations GROUP BY NodeId,ifIndex) AS t;` and `SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT MAX(dt),action FROM reservations GROUP BY NodeId,ifIndex) AS t;`.  The `t.*` rather than `t.action` being the difference in syntax.  These return different results for `t.action`.  Is this another optimiser-black-box quirk?

Comment: We have already agreed upon that there is a bug leading to an incorrect result in `SELECT t.action FROM ...`. And the query `SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT MAX(dt),action ...` must return the same result as `SELECT MAX(dt),action ...` itself of course. Does it? Then this is fine. Doesn't it? Then this is probably the same bug.